# Text Editor Graphical Glitch on Xcode 6.4

Tags: xcode, graphics, text

I'm experiencing a very odd graphical glitch with the code editor, initially I thought it was my machine's graphics going to pot but after further investigation it is definitely tied to Xcode and/or my project file.

This glitch appears to follow my project around, I have tried deleting derived data and userdata from the project folder, I've also made sure all of my fonts are the same (this was suggested in another thread for a similar sounding issue). Very often while editing code the below graphical error occurs, it is very frustrating. Has anyone else encountered this?

I've moved the project across multiple Macs and the problem persists, I would be really grateful for any insight on how to prevent this as I'm nearing the end of a very long project and this has pretty much put a halt to progress.

[image: image of issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Preferences->General tab and uncheck "Show live issues" under Issues. Notice that this is a work around to be able to continue working with Xcode, at least until they issue an official fix. This glitch seems to be noticeable when you have lots of lines of code (1000+).

After this, the glitch will still be happening but not while coding but during building phase. Not perfect but at least you will be able to continue working.

Comment: Great, I had experimented with this and noticed it was still happening on occasion. It's good to have confirmation for what I suspected - this only happens on build now.